# Programmatically dial an existing connection in Windows CE?

Tags: c#, windows-ce, ras

The RAS API for Windows CE is making me cry and, as a C# programmer, I can't make heads or tails of the documentation on MSDN regarding the vast majority of the functions which are available.

I've already scoured the NET for code which allows me to list ACTIVE connections, check a connections status and hang up if needed.

Now what I need is to establish a connection, one that already has been created in Windows CE. The connection has some extra parameters like baud rate, flow control and an "extra settings" string along the lines of `+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet"`.

Now, what little I managed to understand from the MSDN documentation, I can't just tell Windows CE to "dial this connection". I need to retrieve the connections' parameters (phone number, user name, password and I also assume I need those extra parameters like baud rate and so on) and then tell the system to dial THAT.

At this point I'm at a loss, as I've no idea how to do that. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With RAS, you have to enumerate the entries, then use those to tell RAS which entry you want to dial.  It's a bit convoluted, yes, but have you seen [this shared-source project](http://rascf.codeplex.com/)?  It will simplify basic dialing.

Now adding extra settings is a different story, and it's pretty much a nightmare.  RAS doesn't have provisions for adding that extra info - that has to be done with TAPI (there's [a shared source project for that too](http://tapi.codeplex.com/)).  Generally speaking I prefer to just use the control panel UI to set those parameters when I can and just use TAPI to enumerate and dial.

Comment: So... basically, what I need to do, is enumerate all the dial-up connections (in order to get the one I need), and then dial the one using **TAPI**, not RASAPI?

Comment: Also... the documentation for that TAPI project is really lacking, and I can't seem to find a method to list the current dial-up connections. Any chance you could point me in the right way?